# Compiler Error Passing `associatedtype` value from one Protocol to another

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm working in Swift 5.7.  I need to implement what's essentially form validation but with a twist.  Instead of evaluating rules and returning boolean values, I need to throw an error upon failure.

I have the following protocol, which can be added to but otherwise not changed:

```
protocol Valuable {
    associatedtype ValueType
    
    var value: ValueType? { get }
    
    mutating func update(_ newValue: ValueType) throws
}
```

I'm attempting to add an array of rules, conforming to a different protocol, which need to pass in order for the new value to be saved. I have two problems which I'm facing:

- I need to constrain the second protocol to have the same associated type as `Valuable`
- I'm getting a compiler error when I attempt to pass `value` as a parameter to a function in the second protocol: `Member 'validate' cannot be used on a value of type 'any Validatable'; consider using a generic constraint instead`

My understanding of this compiler error (which may be a faulty understanding) is that because `any Validatable` is being consumed, Swift is unable to unbox and/or infer the underlying type. How do I get around this?

For enforcing the same `associatedtype`, I tried adding `associatedtype Rule: Validatable where Rule.T == ValueType` to the `Valuable` protocol, but then the compiler complains that my struct does not conform to `Valuable`.  I looked at other posts regarding constraining protocol types, but it appears that those recommendations either no longer work with Swift 5.7, or are missing something.

Here's a simplified example of my code:

```
enum ValidationError: Error {
    case Invalid(subErrors: [Error])
}

protocol Valuable {
    associatedtype ValueType
    
    var value: ValueType? { get }
    var rules: [any Validatable] { get }
    
    mutating func update(_ newValue: ValueType) throws
}

protocol Validatable {
    associatedtype T
    func validate(_ value: T) throws
}

struct StringValue: Valuable {
    typealias ValueType = String
    var value: String?
    var rules: [any Validatable]
    
    mutating func update(_ newValue: String) throws {
        let errors = rules.compactMap { rule in
            do {
                try rule.validate(newValue) // <~~ Compiler error here
                return nil
            } catch {
                return error
            }
        }
        
        if errors.isEmpty {
            self.value = newValue
        } else {
            throw ValidationError.Invalid(subErrors: errors)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a primary associate type to `Validatable`:

```
protocol Validatable<T> { // add a <T> here
    associatedtype T
    func validate(_ value: T) throws
}
```

so that you can easily specify that "`Validatable` where `T` is `ValueType`" should be the `rules` array element type.

```
// in Valuable
var rules: [any Validatable<ValueType>] { get }

// in StringValue
var rules: [any Validatable<String>]
```

The compiler also seems to be unable to infer the result type of `compactMap`, so you should help it out:

```
let errors: [Error] = rules.compactMap { rule in
          ^^^^^^^^^
```

Also consider adding a primary associated for `Valuable` too. Judging from the protocol names, this seems appropriate and probably will be useful later.

```
protocol Valuable<ValueType> {
```